# React sorting doesn't work right on the first try

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component with a select that changes my `sorting` state

```
const [sorting, setSorting] = useState(""); 
const priceAsc = (r1, r2) => {
    return r2.euroPrice - r1.euroPrice;
  };
  const priceDesc = (r1, r2) => {
    return r1.euroPrice - r2.euroPrice;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sorting);
    switch (sorting) {
      case "price:asc":
        console.log("here!");
        setRoutes(routes.sort(priceAsc));
        break;
      case "price:desc":
        console.log("now here!");
        setRoutes(routes.sort(priceDesc));
        break;
      default:
        setRoutes(routes.sort(priceAsc));
        break;
    }
  }, [sorting]);
```

The problem is if the first time I select price ascending option, my program outputs

```
price:asc
here!
```

which should mean it sorts my array ascending by price, but it's actually sorting it descending. If I change the select then it sorts it like I would expect. So this only happens on the very first time I choose the `ascending` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.sort`sorts the array [in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Because the state must be treated as immutable, you must update the state with a new array.

```
setRoutes([...routes.sort(priceAsc)])
```